# JAX-RS @Path Embedded Variables

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, jax-rs

I'm using the latest Jax-RS + Glassfish versions and I've been trying to version my API. For some reason, if I include embedded variables in my @Path Root Resource Class it doesn't even take the variables in consideration.

```
@Path("/v{versionNum}/tasks")
public class Tasks {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;
}
```

My Context Root is /api

My web.xml includes:

```
 <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Now if I try to hit
    localhost:8080/api/v1/tasks, I get a 404.
If I  hit
    localhost:8080/api/tasks, it works!

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: I set it in the project properties with eclipse, in Web Project Settings

Comment: Did you try witoout {versionNum}? Something like @Path("/vavava/tasks")

Comment: hmm yeah I tried @Path("/v1/tasks") and it still didn't work, but if I change my web.xml servlet-mapping to /v1/* it works, but I don't want that, if I try /v*/* that doesn't work either

Comment: what about @Path("/v{versionNum}") works? Pattern <url-pattern>/v[0-9]/*</url-pattern> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sun-web.xml**

```
<sun-web-app>
  <context-root>/api</context-root>
</sun-web-app>
```

**web.xml**

```
...  
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
...
```

**HelloWorldService.java**

```
@Path("/v{version}/tasks")
```

deploy on GlassFish
`http://localhost:8080/api/v1/tasks` - works well

Comment: I created a new Dynamic Web Project from scratch and included all the Jersey jars properly, put my context root to /api with Glassfish, and I copied your .xml content and it worked! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

localhost:8080/projectname/api/v15/tasks

- projectname: project name
- /api : servlet-mapping
- /v15/tasks : path annotation

Comment: what about context-root? Context-root hide project name